# Basis Element of the Product topology vs. Element of the Basis

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and have some doubts under theorem 20.3 regarding basis element of product topology. It is written that:

> Let $B=(a_1,b_1)\times...\times(a_n,b_n)$ be a basis element for the product topology and let $\bar x =(x_1,...,x_n)$ be an element of $B$.

My doubts are as follows:

1. I am unable to understand the above quoted statement. What does the notation $(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$ stand for?
2. What is the difference between basis element $B$ and an element of $B$? I mean a basis element for the product topology on the cartesian product was defined by $U\times V$ previously in the book where U and V are open sets in X and Y respectively. Then why is it now $(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$ ? And how is it different from the tuple x =(x_1,...,x_n)?

For reference i am attaching the screenshot where i have highlighted the quoted text.[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb R^n$ is a Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $\Bbb R$. The standard base for the topology of $\Bbb R$ is the set of all open intervals $(a,b)$ for $a < b$.

In theorem 15.1 and the example after it Munkres discusses the $\Bbb R^2$ case and notes that the set of products of intervals then is a (standard) base product of copies of $\Bbb R$, as we have here.

So this remark in the proof refers back to that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

1. The $\times$ refers to the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Each $(a_i, b_i)$ is an (open) interval in $\mathbb{R}$. To visualise this, this is a box in the plane without its borders. So, for example,
   $$
   (a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2) = \{ (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a_1 < x_1 < b_1, a_2 < x_2 < b_2 \} .
   $$
   This pattern is then generalised to hold for $\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. A [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for a topology means that every set in the topology can be generated as a union of elements of the basis (these elements are themselves sets). The product topology for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as the one generated by these so-called cylindrical sets - an arbitrary such set is $B = (a_1, b_1) \times \dots \times (a_n, b_n)$. Since $B$ is itself a set (it is the Cartesian product of the $n$ open intervals), that means it contains points (if it is not empty), such as $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: Ok so you have written product for two open intervals $(a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2) = \{ (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a_1 < x_1 < b_1, a_2 < x_2 < b_2 \} $ How can we write product of three open intervals in this notation , i mean $x_1$ and $x_2$ will range from where to where in that case? In this notation i mean

Comment: Will $(a_1, b_1) \times (a_2, b_2) \times (a_3, b_3) = \{ (x_1, x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : a_1 < x_1 < b_1, a_2 < x_2 < b_2,a_3 < x_3 < b_3 \}$ ? Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.